# SSIS: An OLE DB Error has occurred. error code 0x80004005, The peer prematurely closed the connection

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssas

> SSIS error Code DTS_E_OLEDERROR. An OLE DB Error has occurred. error code 0x80004005. An OLE DB record is available. Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server 2016 Analysis Services.” Hresult: 0x80004005 Description: “An error was encountered in the transport layer.”. An OLE DB record is available. Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server 2016 Analysis Services.” Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: “The peer prematurely closed the connection.”.

**Issue encountered:** When trying to run SSAS Cube from SSIS.

**Following SQL server setup:**

1. SSIS: SQL Server 2016 version 13.0.5622.0 (OS 2016 Core Server)
2. SSAS: SQL Server 2016 version 13.0.5102.14 (OS 2012 Server non-Core)

**What we have tested so far:**

1. SSAS: When running SSAS Package directly - No Issues will Occur. Meaning, we remove doubts that concerns issues from SSAS
2. SSIS:SQL Server 2016 version 13.0.5622.0 (OS 2012 Server non-Core) - When running the package under this server, issue will not occur.
3. SSIS: SQL Server 2016 version 13.0.5622.0 (OS 2016 Core Server) - When running Package under this server, Issue will occur.
4. from #3 - Updating Provider from MSOLAP.6 to MSOLAP.7 - Issue still occur.

**Process:**

1. Create SSIS with Analysis Service Processing Task
2. have connection string : Data Source=;Initial Catalog=;Provider=MSOLAP.7;Integrated Security=SSPI;Impersonation Level=Impersonate;
3. Create SSAS Process : Any Process will do as long as it will run
4. Run SSIS < Error will occur once SSIS executed

Has anybody encounter the same or the issue with similar like ours?

Comment: Can you access your SSAS installation from *Core Server*? What is the user account under which SSIS package is run on this server?

Comment: hi @Ferdipux, you mean if I can access the SSAS Server from the Core Server? We'll I havent check this one, I'll coordinate with our DBA if they can do this. Appreciate the advise. I'll get back to you if I have feedbacks.

Comment: @Ferdipux we were able to test the connectivity of the SSIS Server to SSAS Server and it is working fine. We will try to look for another ways. I'll post it if we find something. If there is anyone have other ideas to test out the issue it would be best to share. Thanks.

Comment: If I understand your configuration right, you have server 1 - with OS non-Core, SSAS and SSIS, where package is fine. And OS Core, SSIS only, where package is failing. If so, next things to check - access to SSAS as a service from the network, are servers in the same domain, how do you run package on OS-Core server.

Comment: hello, I encountered the same error in OLE DB connection, have you figured it out?

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue the only change being the OS is windows 2016 server non-core. Initially the Analysis Engine was running on SQL Server 2017 RTM Version. After applying the Latest Cumulative Update (CU20) the issue got resolved. May be it worked in my case hence thought of sharing so that it could help others.

Below are the details

OS: Windows 2016 Server non Core
SQL Version: 2017 RTM

when executed the Package from the same server we got the below error
**"The Following System Occurred"** .

However when executed remotely we got the error
**"The peer prematurely closed the connection"**

Answer (score -1):

The problem is in 32BITS driver version. Use 64 bits driver and will work fine

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.